# restful service requires username and password to get the token, is it ok to save the credentials(user and pass) in server side nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, rest, fetch

I have a app which takes a csv from user, converts it to json and saves the json file in S3 bucket on AWS. Then I am using restful services from oracle to push that data to oracle jde.

User can't upload a file without being "approved" before hand - its a manual process for now, but their email needs to be added to S3 bucket first
The web app checks if the email exists in S3 then allows the file upload to happen, if it doesn't exist then file upload is rejected.

I don't have any other "user authentication" set up for now.

Next, in order to get the token from the external API, I need to feed it a service account username and password, currently, since its still in development I am keeping the username and password on my server side nodejs in a object which I pass into the api call to get the token.

For the time being we don't plan on having user login, so that being said how can I secure the username and password but still be able to get a token for "authenticated emails allowed to upload"?

Basically, I assume just keeping it in variable server side node is not a good idea, so looking for another way of storing it somewhere and still being able to make the call to the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the time being we don't plan on having user login, so that being
>   said how can I secure the username and password but still be able to
>   get a token for "authenticated emails allowed to upload"?

You can't. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, those are not "authenticated emails", they are "pre-approved email addresses". You still need to authenticate your users to help secure the app.

> So do I still hash and salt the hardcoded username and password and save to db?

You can't salt and hash your passwords because you're intending to reuse the original password. That puts the onus on you to secure the passwords. Don't play that game. Many people reuse the same passwords for lots of different accounts. Do you want to have to send an email to your users letting them know you had a security breach and that they need to reset all their passwords?

Comment: So its fine I can create user authentication, but in order to actually access the external server API, we can't really create multiple usernames and passwords to connect to it. It has to be one unique username and password. How can I handle that? Once user logs in I still need to get node to use the unique username and password for API to get the token.

Comment: After rereading your original question I see I missed the part about the service account. Okay, you should still authenticate the end users with the pre-approved email addresses. As to securing the service account's credentials, do you have a build process for deploying the app? It's generally a bad practice to keep things like usernames and passwords in your source control repo. You could reference an environment variable from the process.env object, but you need something to set the value on the server. You could use a build process for this.

Comment: thanks, i don't have a build process yet. I did consider using environment variables. could you direct me in right direction to get an idea of how to do this build process with the env variable? thanks!

Comment: That would depend on your build process. But assuming you were using something like Jenkins with Docker, you could look at these: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/
https://ifritltd.com/2017/08/12/dockerizing-jenkins-part-3-securing-password-with-docker-compose-docker-secret-and-jenkins-credentials-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I assume just keeping it in variable server side node is not a good idea

That's right, it's not a good idea. For example what if your server dies? Then you'll loose that value. Not to mention the added cost of your RAM since everything will be stored in memory.

## Solution

- Store the credentials in a **database**. It can be in SQL or NoSQL, and the server can be in whatever you prefer

## Considerations

- Don't forget to hash the password before storing it
- Add some [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) when hashing
- To validate a password, just hash the one you got from your client and compare it to the hash you stored in your database
- Use **HTTPS** for traffic between your client and server

Comment: Or better yet, since you're using AWS, go ahead and use Cognito.

Comment: @molamk I wont be getting any user input besides the file upload. So do I still hash and salt the hardcoded username and password and save to db? how do i use it after to get the token? do i need to unsalt and hash it?

Comment: The username no, but the password you definitely need to hash it (and salt it). Also there's no "unsalt" since you're directly comparing hashes to validate your password. This _validation_ is the one you need to generate your token

Comment: @molamk even If I create user login/authentication, their login can't be tied to the server the API lives. That server can only have one service account which we can use to access the API token and routes and we can't really give that out to users. So it would have to be something like user logs in then they can make the api call because once authenticated the "service account" info will be passed into the API call. Is keeping that credential on a db and getting it after user logs the good way then? Wondering what my options are